# Add node.exe installation path into environment variables path?

Tags: node.js, git-bash

I'm using Gitbash for the first time and after I installed Nodejs, I was asked to "Add your node.exe installation path (example: `c:\Program Files\nodejs\10.15.3`) into environment variables path

Anyone know how to do this (what to put in the command line) or what they mean by this? Do they mean to use `set` ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this and add the full path to your node.exe to the list
https://ginesys.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/PUB/pages/1900549/How+To+Set+the+PATH+variable+in+environment+variable+in+Windows

Answer (score 2):

To add a path to the path variable, use the **setx** command.

Example:

```
setx path "%path%;c:\directoryPath"
```

In your case:

```
setx path"%path%;c:\Program Files\nodejs\10.15.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the node variable in the first place, like that

[image]

That work for me.