# I can't install Atom Packages

Tags: package, atom-plugins

anyone can help me I can't install Packages In Atom.
here is an error:**'node.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Comment: Do you have [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) installed on your system? Please check the [Atom Discussion](https://discuss.atom.io/) forum first.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Download & Install Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
2. Try again your package installation

If still doesn't work, just [Add node.exe installation path into environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57729228/add-node-exe-installation-path-into-environment-variables-path) manually.